# Xcode Local Web App in Safari

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, web

I already make a Web Application (php, javascript,css files) which run with a local server (Wampserver and Safari in the Iphone) and I would like to know if it's possible to run php files in Xcode 4 (with an UIWebView or with an UIApplication) ?

I look forward to your response..

Edit : in fact i would like to run my local php file included in my xcode project with safari ..

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean by "run".

If you are asking if you can put the PHP scripts into your iOS application and have them run, then no, not without porting a PHP interpreter to iOS and embedding that interpreter in your application.

If you are asking if you can run the PHP scripts on the local server and have the iOS application access them, then yes, so long as the device can connect to the web server.

Comment: I enthusiastically support this answer

Answer (score 0):

It will not run your PHP code, unless you port an interpreter.

Comment: @Jim Xcode will run PHP in the iOS Simulator using a web view. Just like a normal website. Added that to answer.

Comment: A web view corresponds with a web browser, not a web server.  PHP runs on the server, not in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iOS Simulator to access the PHP file through a `UIWebView` and it will be executed on the server. I would assume this is the answer you want.

If you want to run the PHP file on the device itself, this is not possible. There is no PHP interpreter in iOS.